# How create a space between elements (5px)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I have two grids i want to create spacing beetween elements, the space must be 5px horizontally, i have use the spacing={5} but not worked

```js
<Grid container direction={'row'} spacing={5}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <FormControl
            className={classes.formControl}
            fullWidth
        >
            <InputLabel id="issue-label">Issue</InputLabel>
            <Select
                className={classes.select}
                id="issue"
                onChange={handleIssue}
            >
                <MenuItem value="" disabled>
                   Please select
                </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TextField
            fullWidth={true}
            multiline
        />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: from which library `Grid` Component is from you are using

Comment: @Chandan from '@material-ui/core'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Grid component documentation page](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing), the number in the `spacing` prop is multiplied by 8px. So `spacing={5}` means that the gap between two items is actually 40px.

Replace the `spacing` prop with `style={{ gap: 5 }}`. This should set the flexbox gap between items to 5px.

Comment: Just a note about the `gap` adoption on browsers, which is good but not super-high nowadays. https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
.grid-container {
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

Here is the Reference

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-gap.asp